# C# linq query, select parent list based on the condition of nest list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have a list of projects with a list of project members for each project as follows

```
public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public class Project
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string  Title { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Member{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to select projects for a list of member Ids using LINQ, thank you!

Comment: I assume you ask for a function that has a parameter `List<Member>`. What should be the return value of this function? Something like `List<Project>`? Should the function return only the projects where all members from input are listed, or at least one member? Or you ask for `Dictionary<Member, List<Project>>` where for each member we get all projects where they are listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
        var projects = new List<Project>();
        List<Guid>searched_value = new List<Guid>();
        var newList = projects.Where(p => p.Members.Any(m => searched_value.Any(s => s == m.Id))).ToList();
```

Edited to reflect the OP wants to check against a List

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of `Guid`s, you can check against it by using `.Contains()` inside `.Where()`:

```
var projects = new List<Project>();
//Add projects

var memberIds = new List<Guid>();
//Add member IDs

var memberProjects = projects
    .Where(p => p.Members.Any(m => memberIds.Contains(m.Id)));
```